# Concatenate columns and then grouped them within specific range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need some help with my MySQL problem. I'm trying to concatenate two columns and then insert the results into a single temp column. However, the concatenated rows should be grouped, based on a range, in the temp column. I'm open to any suggestions as I'm mysql experience is limited.Here's what I have;

### Current Situation

- I have two tables

One contains individual bible verses;

```
CREATE temporary TABLE `bible_text_temp` (
`text_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`book_index` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`chapter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`verse` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`verse_text` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`version_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`life_verse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`verse_html` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`text_id`),UNIQUE KEY  `text_id_UNIQUE` (`text_id`))
```

The other table has the verse numbers for specific category. E.g. The table contains all verse numbers that's associated with love;

```
CREATE TABLE `final_verse_import` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `book_index` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL, `verse_from` int(11) NOT NULL, `verse_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `life_category` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,`life_tag_1` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,`life_tag_2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,`verses` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2047 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

- I'm trying to concatenate the `verse_html` and `verse_text` columns in the `bible_text_temp` table as verses and insert it into another temp table, called `hold_verses` by joining on the `final_verse_import` using the following query

  ```
  INSERT INTO hold_verses (book_index, chapter, verse_from, verse_to, verses)
  SELECT a.book_index, a.chapter, b.verse_from, b.verse_to, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.verse_html, a.verse_text SEPARATOR ' ') AS verses 
  FROM bible_text_temp  a
  INNER JOIN  final_verse_import b
  ON a.book_index = b.book_index
  AND a.chapter = b.chapter
  AND a.verse = b.verse_from
  AND a.version_id = 3
  GROUP BY id
  ```
- The above query seems to work fine if I only want the first verse for each row in the `final_verse_import` table. Meaning that I'm getting the correct `CONCAT` value for each verse row in the `hold_verses` table based on the `verse_from` column in the `final_verse_import` if I'm looking to only return one verse in the `CONCAT` column
- However, some rows in the `final_verse_import` consist of more than one verse. E.g a Bible verse about love can consist of more than one verse, like `romans 4: 2 - 4` (multiple verses) instead of just `romans 4:2`(single verse). To accommodate this I have another column in the `final_verse_import` table called `verse_to`. If this column is populated there will be more than one verse for a category verse row. If it's not populated (`NULL`) there's only one verse. E.g. for `romans 4:2 -4` the `verse_from` will be `2` and the verse_to will be `4`. Please note that category verse will be everything from 2 and between 4, so it will be verse 2, verse 3, verse 4.
- I would like to return all verses for a category verse row, based on both the `verse_from` and `verse_to` as the `CONCAT` value in the `hold_verses.verses` column and not just the first verse (`verse_from`). Therefore the above query will not work as it only return one verse for each category verse row.

### Questions

1. how do I modify the query to return all verse between `verse_from` and `verse_to` as the CONCAT value and not just the `verse_to` value? I was trying to use the following; `AND a.verse BETWEEN b.verse_from AND b.verse_to` in the `WHERE` clause, but it seems to ignore all rows that has `final_verse_import.verse_to` = `NULL`.
2. How do I include results that has `final.verse_import.verse_to` = `NULL`? Some category verses will only be one verse, I need to return them as well.
3. How do I sort the list of `CONCAT` verses in a `hold_verses.verses` column in order `ASC`? Currently when I use the BETWEEN statement the rows with multiple verse is not displayed in order. E.g. If I return a `CONCAT` value for verse `romans 4: 2 -4` the results will be listed as verse 2, verse 4, verse 3 in the `CONCAT` column, instead of verse 2, verse 3, verse 4. I realize my query might be wrong, so this could potentially be fixed if I use the correct query.

Apologies in advance if my questions and descriptions are not clear. I've got a habit making stuff overly complex :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do this in the application that is using the data.  In other words, instead of trying to lump everything together into a single string in the database, have the calling application select multiple rows and then iterate through the rows and manipulate the data there.

Comment: I need to export the data into csv once I've consolidated everything and then hand-off the flat files to someone that will import it into a CMS. Therefore, the data is not directly getting consumed and I would need to try and extract it using MySQL in the appropriate format.

Comment: So you're also going to need some way to escape comma characters?

Comment: Nope that should be fine. Strings will be placed within " " in the csv file, so the commas in the strings should not affect the comma field separators in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
select
    ref.id,
    group_concat(txt.verse, ' ', txt.verse_text, ' ' order by txt.verse),
    group_concat('<b>', txt.verse, '</b> ', txt.verse_html, '<br/>' order by txt.verse)
from
    bible_text_temp txt
    join final_verse_import ref on 
        txt.book_index = ref.book_index 
        and txt.chapter = ref.chapter 
        and txt.verse >= ref.verse_from
        and txt.verse <= ifnull(ref.verse_to, ref.verse_from)
where
    ref.life_category = 'LOVE'
group by 
    ref.id
order by
    ref.id, txt.verse
;
```

Here's the full example.

```
use example;

drop table if exists bible_text_temp;

drop table if exists final_verse_import;

CREATE TABLE `bible_text_temp` (
    `text_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `book_index` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `verse` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `verse_text` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `life_verse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `verse_html` varchar(8000) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`text_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY  `text_id_UNIQUE` (`text_id`)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `final_verse_import` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `book_index` varchar(500) NOT NULL, 
        `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        `verse_from` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        `verse_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
        `life_category` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
        `life_tag_1` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
        `life_tag_2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
        `verses` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2047 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 31, 'Do to others as you would have them do to you.','<html>Do to others as you would have them do to you.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 32, '"If you love those who love you, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' love those who love them.','<html>"If you love those who love you, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' love those who love them.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 33, 'And if you do good to those who are good to you, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' do that.','<html>And if you do good to those who are good to you, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' do that.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 34, 'And if you lend to those from whom you expect repayment, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' lend to ''sinners,'' expecting to be repaid in full.','<html>And if you lend to those from whom you expect repayment, what credit is that to you? Even ''sinners'' lend to ''sinners,'' expecting to be repaid in full.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 35, 'But love your enemies, do good to them, and lend to them without expecting to get anything back. Then your reward will be great, and you will be sons of the Most High, because he is kind to the ungrateful and wicked.','<html>But love your enemies, do good to them, and lend to them without expecting to get anything back. Then your reward will be great, and you will be sons of the Most High, because he is kind to the ungrateful and wicked.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('LUKE', 6, 36, 'Be merciful, just as your Father is merciful.','<html>Be merciful, just as your Father is merciful.</html>');


insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('ROMANS', 12, 9, 'Love must be sincere. Hate what is evil; cling to what is good.', '<html>Love must be sincere. Hate what is evil; cling to what is good.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('ROMANS', 12, 10, 'Be devoted to one another in brotherly love. Honor one another above yourselves.', '<html>Be devoted to one another in brotherly love. Honor one another above yourselves.</html>');
insert into bible_text_temp (book_index, chapter, verse, verse_text, verse_html) values ('ROMANS', 12, 11, 'Never be lacking in zeal, but keep your spiritual fervor, serving the Lord.', '<html>Never be lacking in zeal, but keep your spiritual fervor, serving the Lord.</html>');

insert into final_verse_import (book_index, chapter, verse_from, verse_to, life_category) values ('LUKE', 6, 31, 36, 'LOVE'); 
insert into final_verse_import (book_index, chapter, verse_from, verse_to, life_category) values ('ROMANS', 12, 9, null, 'LOVE'); 

select
    ref.id,
    group_concat(txt.verse, ' ', txt.verse_text, ' ' order by txt.verse),
    group_concat('<b>', txt.verse, '</b> ', txt.verse_html, '<br/>' order by txt.verse)
from
    bible_text_temp txt
    join final_verse_import ref on 
        txt.book_index = ref.book_index 
        and txt.chapter = ref.chapter 
        and txt.verse >= ref.verse_from
        and txt.verse <= ifnull(ref.verse_to, ref.verse_from)
where
    ref.life_category = 'LOVE'
group by 
    ref.id
order by
    ref.id, txt.verse
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @John, but it doesn't solve my original problems. This is what I'm struggling with;

 1. The verses are not `CONCAT` in the correct verse order. If you add `txt.verse` to the output `(group_concat(txt.verse, txt.verse_text, ' ')` you'll notice the order of the verses are incorrect and not in sequence of verse numbers 

2. I also want to return verses in the `final_verses_import` that has `verse_to = NULL` not just verse with a value for `verse_from` and `verse_to`. 

Any suggestions on these issues?

Comment: You are correct sir, sorry for the oversight on my part. There needs to be an order by in the group_concat statement (corrected in the edited answer above).  This fixes the order by issue.

Comment: ...and an ifnull should take care of the case where verse_to is null (also corrected in the edited answer above, more info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks John, This helps me a lot. I appreciate the helping hand. I would've up-voted your answer if I had enough reputation :(